# Eliminating ghost voltage and breaking ground loops in a system

Tags: ac, switch-mode-power-supply, linear, capacitive, ground-loop

[image]
The above illustration is a setup I use where amplifier outputs go to a data acquisition system through BNC cables. The data acquisition system is earth-grounded. Mains system voltage Line to Neutral is 230VAC.

A1, A2, A3. A4 are force-transducer amplifiers(they output 0-10V DC signals) which are powered by an SMPS type 24VDC power supply(PSU in the illustration). As far as I found out there is a ghost voltage(when BNCs are not plugged/ when floating) between the BNC connector tips and the earth(marked as gray in the illustration) due to SMPS Y-capacitor leakage. This ghost voltage is 85VAC when the PSU is ON and 180VAC when it is OFF.

Even though this ghost/phantom voltage is safe due to microampere level currents, It causes a very unpleasant sensation. I want to eliminate or minimize it.

If I wire the DC GND of the PSU output to the earth the issue disappears, but then since the DAQ system is also earth grounded there will be ground loops.

**My questions are:**

1-) If I replace the SMPS with a linear supply, would the ghost voltage disappear? And if so, how can I be sure if the linear power supply I buy is 100% linear?

2-) In another forum, I read some suggestions which were wiring the DC output GND of the SMPS to the earth through a 100 ohm series resistor or using anti-parallel diodes. It was mentioned, one of these supposed to drain the leakage currents but break ground loops. Any idea about this work around and how to implement it?

Comment: The problem is not necessarily going to disappear if you were to start using a linear power supply. It is indeed less likely that a linear power supply would have an inbuilt EMI filter for suppressing noise from the power supply itself. But it is rather common that AC power line filtering will still be applied in a linear power supply application to keep "system" level noise from coupling back into the AC power mains.

Comment: This is not EMI noise. This is ghost voltage, caused by the Y-caps which are used to suppress the EMI in SMPSs. The ghost voltage is 50Hz. I didnt get what you mean why using linear supply wouldnt solve the issue.

Comment: oh you mean the linear power supplies use line filters ?

Comment: Yes. It is a very common requirement that equipment that uses linear power supplies also must use AC line filters. Those line filters also contain line connected capacitors. They have to be used to (a) keep system noise from getting out onto the AC line and (b) to keep noise on the AC line from getting into the system and upsetting its operation. Such filters may or may not be present inside the linear power supply itself. You will find there is a whole industry of power line filter components that get designed into systems that will still have the possibility to produce "ghost" voltages.

Comment: Try connecting the amplifier DC ground to the DAC system earth.  You can use a spare BNC cable connected to a spare socket on the DAC.  Make sure all the BNC cables run in the same loom.

Comment: @skvery It makes sense what you suggest as well thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ghost voltage is caused by the switch mode power supply's internal EMI reduction capacitors AND it is likely that the SMPS you have used either doesn't require an earth connection for safety or EMC reasons.

If the SMPS did use earth then it would route EMI reduction capacitors directly to earth instead. This would kill-off the ghost voltage you are seeing.

As an alternative, try earthing the negative SMPS output lead.

You should also consider operating the DAQ with balanced inputs so that any common-mode earth voltage problem is much alleviated. I know this means halving the number of avaliable channels (in some DAQs) but you will get better measurements and in the collection of telemetry information most of the industry I know of goes down the differential route if they can (even if the signals to be measured are single ended).

Comment: Yes I tried that and wrote in my question. But that causes ground loops in the system because now both sides are earth-grounded. I want to kill the ghost voltage and break the ground loops at the same time. For some reason I cannot change DAQ confg. How about a 100% linear power supply?

Comment: I also recommended differential inputs as an afterthought. Also, it's likely that you could use a 100 nF capacitor from negative output to earth and reduce this problem significantly. Make sure it's rated at 200 volts or more though.

Comment: I see but cap blocks DC ground loops how about 50Hz ground loops? The cap will drain the leakage from SMPS to earth but also will pass 50Hz ground loops isnt it?

Comment: Well, 100 nF has an impedance of 32 kohm at 50 Hz so you are not going to get much more than a few hundred microamp ground current flowing. Put it into perspective.

Comment: Oh I see your point. I will try wiring a 100nF cap between the output DC GND of the SMPS and the earth. Good you mentioned also I have to use cap with at least 200V rating, I would skip that detail. Why around 100nF by the way? thnx

Comment: The internal capacitors in SMPSs are about 1nF to 10 nF. A 100 nF will be at least ten times lower in impedance and hence reduce the ghost voltage by at least ten times. Maybe 1 uF could be considered if space isn't an issue.

Comment: Space isnt issue I just need to find a 1uF 200V electrolytic capacitor right?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you measure the ghost voltage using an AC measurement. If it says 100 volts or less then a 200 volt capacitor will be fine. If it says more than 100 VAC then make the capacitor DC voltage voltage twice as big (my numbers include a safety factor).

Comment: I have this already: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/293/e-uld-884079.pdf 400V 1.2uF electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: Go for it!!!!!!

Comment: I think film capacitors are more suitable... Is it save to use electrolytic ones, we do not know the polarity of the _noise_?

Comment: Don't use electrolytics for sure. Film caps are probably best rather than ceramic and you could use an X or Y rated one for peace of mind.

Comment: How about this one?: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/polypropylene-film-capacitors/1262225/ 1μF Polypropylene Film Capacitor (PP) 310 V ac, 630 V dc. It says Suppression Class X2.

Comment: That should be fine.